# Конвертация в JPEG

Tags: php

Что использовать для конвертации пользовательских фотографий в JPEG?

Comment: https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine

Answer (score 1):

Как насчёт ImageMagick (http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php), например?
Не всегда идеально, но так как задача сформулирована не очень конкретно то, думаю, должно сгодиться.
Правда понадобится время что бы разобраться, так как я лично не особо много мануалов и описаний функций на русском видел.